# How can I change the functions in the top and bottom of a double integral?

Tags: calculus

How can I go from an integral looking like this:
$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1}    f(x,y) dxdy $

To an integral looking like this: 
$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2x}    f(x,y) dxdy $

I just want to know what the process is behind it and how we can change the integrals around?

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the order of integration you need to think about the area your integral is being calculated on. It goes from $x$ is $\dfrac y2$ to $1$ and $y$ from $0$ to $2$. Sketch these two curves to visualize it.

You should consider the range of $y$ values and then try to express the range of $x$ values as a function of $y$.

Then you get $\int_0^1\int_0^{2x}f(x,y)dxdy$

Comment: @George Harrison If you find my answer helpful then accept the answer $\checkmark$ :)